# How to use htaccess to redirect from www to non-www version of the site

Tags: htaccess, redirects

I have a wordpress website

```
mywebsite.net
```

on the wwww version `www.mywebsite.net` wordpress doesn't load

so  want that if the user open the www version of my website is redirect to the non-wwww version

here my .htaccess

```
# Do not remove this line or mod_rewrite rules and search engine friendly URLs will stop working
RewriteBase /

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

# Enable cross-domain CORS

<FilesMatch "\.(ttf|otf|woff)$">
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
        Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</IfModule>
</FilesMatch>

# WordPress SEO - XML Sitemap Rewrite Fix
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^sitemap_index.xml$ /index.php?sitemap=1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+?)-sitemap([0-9]+)?.xml$ /index.php?sitemap=$1&sitemap_n=$2 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Ideally, you should only have 1 `RewriteEngine On` and 1 `RewriteBase` directive at the top of your .htaccess file.

Comment: thx @AndreaF for " Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*" "

Answer (score 1):

You can redirect your site from www to non-www version by 2 diff. ways :

**First Method is**

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

You can use above code in you Htaccess. But it will be something like hardcoded code as you have to specify domain name. It will work fine.

**Second Method is :**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Put above code in your Htaccess file.It is dynamic code. Here no need to specify domain name.

Comment: Seems totally ignored :(

Comment: Is it not working?

Comment: Exactly. I have tried but doesn't change.

Comment: For me same method is working..

Comment: @AndreaF The above directives need to go at the top your .htaccess file, _before_ the WordPress rewrites.